# Adding custom prefix to Orders & Invoices

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

Currently i am using Magento version 1.9.2.4. 
In the admin dashboard under sales, i would like to add a prefix to the order and invoice numbers. Currently they are both numbers are increment by 1 and look something like this "100000094". I would like to add a prefix so that this becomes something like "INV-1000000094". I was thinking that this would be done by using the 'Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Type' class but i am unsure. Can someone point me in the right direction.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom prefix in order by rewrite rewrite class Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Type and make changes in the prefix as per your requirement

`public function fetchNewIncrementId($storeId = null)
{
    $incrementId = parent::fetchNewIncrementId($storeId);

```
$incrementId = 'custom-prefix' . $incrementId;

return $incrementId;
```

}`

Thanks